# not getting Radiobutton value from View - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have few questions with yes / no radiobutton answer.

I am trying to save the selected value ( radiobutton value) to the Answers table in my database. however the selected value is coming back with null.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAnswers", "MyController"))
    <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.answerValue[i], true) Yes @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.answerValuer[i], false) No</td>
         <input type = "submit" name = "actionType" value = "SaveAnswers"/>
```

**Model**

```
Public List <bool> answerValue {get;set;}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SaveAnswers(string actionType)
    {
        Answers userAnswers = new Answers();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (actionType == "Save")
            {
                    userAnswers.value = model.answerValue[i];
                    db.SaveChanges();
     }
        }
        return View(actionType);
    }
```

It is not picking up the selection in my controller and its showing its null...

Comment: Please use Chrome Developer Tools to show the payload being POSTed to the server.

Comment: I will look up how to get this tool.. thank you

Comment: It is built into Chrome. Control-Shift-I. Click the `Network` tab.

Comment: thank you.. you mean Chrome Console :).. thanks I just debugged it and I got this error in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It is basically failing to get the selected values.. when I debugged it in Visual  Studio it shows that the answerValue[i] is Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try adding the model as a input onto the controller, you will need to replace model with the class name for your model

```
public ActionResult SaveAnswers(string actionType, Model model)
   {
      Answers userAnswers = new Answers();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (actionType == "Save")
        {
                userAnswers.value = model.answerValue[i];
                db.SaveChanges();
 }
    }
    return View(actionType);
}
```